# klocwork CWARN.SIGNEDBIT on unsigned char

Tags: c++, char, klocwork

I have **C++ code** which contains:

```
struct Struct
{
    uint8_t varA : 1;
    uint8_t varB : 1;
    uint8_t varC : 1;
};
```

When I am running **Klocwork 10** on it, I get a warning:

```
CWARN.SIGNEDBIT (4:Review) Analyze
Bit field 'varA' has one bit and is signed
```

And same for other variables in this struct.
**uint8_t is unsigned char typedef**. When i am trying to use **signed char** then I get an error, not a warning like here. Using **unsigned int** solves problem but i want to use **char** instead.

My question here is: **why this warning appears and how to solve it?**

Comment: I suggest contacting Klocwork and submitting this as a bug.  Worst case, they will explain it and help you resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is a Klocwork 10 bug, I will add this as an exception to the test output. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

KlocWork may be picking at nits here.
Bit fields should be of an integer type, not of a character type.

Try declaring the bit fields as unsigned int.

The compiler should pack the bits into the smallest data type that can contain all the bits.

Check your assembly language listing to see the data type that the compiler is using.

Answer (score 0):

This issue(FP) has been fixed on Klocwork 2017.1 version.
Upgrade Klocwork from v10 to v12 to verify.